# Proper nav tab configuration

Tags: html, css, tabs, bootstrap-modal

I want to have a dynamic navbar so that I have three tabs:

The behaviour should be that when I click into a tab, it redirects me to the part of the page where that tab meaning is, and there is the nav tab as well so I could navigate. Some images showing what I try to explain:

[image: First tab and below would be the description]

[image: Second tab with miniaturas below]

[image: The third tab]

What I want is to navigate through those tabs and somehow, my code doesn't achieve that.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">                                      
<li role="presentation" {if $nvTb eq 0} class="active" style="color: #9a8745" {/if}>
    <a role="tab" {if $nvTb eq 1} id="fichaScroll" {else} data-toggle="tab" {/if}>                            
        {assign var="iddiccionario" value=$arrayProductoSubmenu["ficha"]["iddiccionario"]}
        {$diccionario.$iddiccionario}
    </a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" {if $nvTb eq 1} class="active" style="color: #9a8745" {/if}>
    <a role="tab" 
       {if $nvTb eq 0} id="galeriaScroll" {else} data-toggle="tab" {/if}> 

        {$diccionario.dic_miniaturas}
    </a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" {if $nvTb eq 2} class="active" style="color: #9a8745" {/if}>
    <a role="tab" {if $nvTb eq 0} id="opinionesScroll" {else} data-toggle="tab" {/if}>
        {$diccionario.dic_opiniones_productos}
    </a>
</li>
```

Any help?

Here's also an image of the whole page.

[image: All page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this in a new answer because it is really big and it would mess up the other answer. You might change the appearance of the navbar and add the css to it. But that should be simple.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="150" id="home">
<div id="Description">
 <div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="#Description">Description</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Thumbnails">Thumbnails</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Customer_Reviews">Customer Reviews</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <h2>Description</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
 </div>
</div>
 
 <hr />
 
<div id="Thumbnails">
 <div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#Description">Description</a></li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#Thumbnails">Thumbnails</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Customer_Reviews">Customer Reviews</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <h2>Thumbnails</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
 </div>
</div>

 <hr />

<div id="Customer_Reviews">
 <div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
   <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
     <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#Description">Description</a></li>
       <li><a href="#Thumbnails">Thumbnails</a></li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#Customer_Reviews">Customer Reviews</a></li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <h2>Customer Reviews</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..</p>
 </div>
</div>
 
 <!-- add the script for smooth scrolling -->
 <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script rel="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
   if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
     var target = $(this.hash);
     target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
     if (target.length) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 750);
    return false;
     }
   }
    });
  });
 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [here](http://schooltool.github.io/index.html)?

Maybe check out this file [here](https://github.com/SchoolTool/schooltool.github.io/blob/master/index.html). (Source Code of the upper page)

How it works?

The anchor tags in the navbar are referring to "#home" for example, `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">SchoolTool</a>`, the destination is located via the id-tag `<div id="home"><p>The Home section </p></div>`.

It should then jump to this position.

If you want to make the scrolling smooth, check out this script:

```
<script rel="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 750);
                return false;
              }
            }
          });
        });
    </script>
```

It does simply remove the tag from your shown url in browser and do a smooth scrolling with 750 milliseconds.

Comment: I have three navbars located at the subsections of Descriptions, Thumbnails and Customer Reviews. These three navbars are identical, all with three tabs. What I want is if I click into the third navbar, go to Customer Reviews, which as well has that navbar and then, if I click to Description, go to the Description subsection.